# cant receive push notifications only at home wifi

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

that's my problem. when i am at my home connected with wifi, my wifi bars stay white, and my htc inspire 4g (jellytime) nor my wife's samsung s3 receive any notifications.

if we switch back to data connection, all our hangouts, whatsapps etc notifications
begin to arrive.

i know this is some type of problem with my wifi config or maybe ISP problem, but how can i test the conectivity to GCM servers from any device and debug the real problem? this could be DNS, or TCP connection timeout, etc...

thanks in advance.

ps: i already tried switching the router to 802.11g only, and fix one wireless channel, but that doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems not to be with the GCM server or your third party server or even your code if you are able to see the push notifications on your device when you are connected to 3G/4G. The issue is with the settings, Please check you system settings or other applications settings, as "google settings".

Also make sure that you are implementing your WiFi class/code with the WakefulBroadcastReceiver. (As you might have done with the C2dm Service).

And also your maifest file has "android.permission.INTERNET" & "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" permissions

Hope that would help!!